# automatic tool for html code samples rendering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, github-pages

I have built this jquery plugin: 
[filters](https://github.com/ohadpartuck/jquery-filters-plugin/).

I now want to document it in it's own page.

The problem is that it takes too long.

I want to copy and paste code sample to an online tool and output a copy paste html to place in my documentation page.

output result should look good as `stackoverflow` or bootstrap. [example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tools like:

- [Documenter](http://revaxarts-themes.com/documenter/)
- [Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.org/)

These generate documentation HTML and CSS, which you can copy and paste it in your own GitHub page. A few popular sites using them:

- [BootStrap DatePicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/)
- [ruffus](http://ruffus.readthedocs.org/)
- [Substance D](https://substanced.readthedocs.org/)
- [Documenter Docs](http://revaxarts-themes.com/documenter/docs/)